# Adding methods after fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment that is a "timer" that I can add anywhere. In the fragment I change a textView programatically, and it runs beautifully. My problem is when it comes to using a view from the layout inflated by the constructor(? Not sure if that's the right terminology) in another method below it.

```
public class Timer_fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    int testpins;
    String testedpin;
    TextView text;  
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timer_frag, container, false);

    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pwd_status);
    text.setText("Setting text in fragment not main");
    /* set the TextView's text, click listeners, etc. */
    updateStatus();
    return v;
}
```

All of that code works with no errors but when I try to add this method:

```
private void updateStatus() {
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pwd_status);
            testPin();

            text.setText(testedpin);                         
        }
```

I get a red line under findViewById saying `The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Timer_fragment`.

I thought about inflating the view in all of my methods and not returning them, but surely that would affect performance somehow right?

*Just tried inflating the layout before using the view but I get an error on the word `inflater` and `container` saying that they can't be resolved.*

Am I going about this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have a member variable in the scope of your Fragment called `text`.  Don't re-declare it in your methods, just assign it.

```
text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pwd_status);
```

and

```
private void upateStatus() {
        testPin();
        text.setText(testedpin);                         
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, my problem was just accessing the views.

Answer (score 1):

The method 'findViewById' is provided by the activity. While this class extends Fragment, you will not have access to activity related method calls unless you provide the activity to the fragment.  Check out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)

Basically, either pass in the instance of the activity to the Timer_fragment:

```
private final Activity _activity;

Timer_fragment(Activity activity)
{
    _activity = activity;
}
...

private void updateStatus()
{
    TextView text = (TextView) _activity.findViewById(R.id.pwd_status);
    testPin();

    text.setText(testedpin);                         
}
```

Or set the text of the view from within whichever activity is being used, and not from within the timer class.

Comment: Since I am going to be reusing this fragment, and it has a lot of other methods. Do you recommend I just pass in the instance for ALL of the other methods I have?

Comment: If you pass the instance into the constructor, the Timer_Fragment class will have access to it in all of its methods via the member variable (you don't have to pass it anywhere after that). However, its all about what you are trying to do.  How often do you need to call updateStatus() ie: Can you make use of @Sparky's answer and just do the work elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `findViewById` with `getActivity().findViewById`.

findViewById method is defined inside the Activity class. Fragments aren’t activites. But the fragment can get a reference to the Activity that added it to a screen using the method getActivity.